# Installing an additional redistributable file with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno setup to install my tool together with some dlls. However, I need to run a microsoft redistributable .exe during my setup. How can embed it into the setup process?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to install additional redistributables with your application, you can add them to the setup using a normal `[Files]` entry with the `dontcopy` flag.

You can then extract this during the `PrepareToInstall` event function using the `ExtractTemporaryFile()` function and run it using `Exec()`.

This method will also allow you to check the exit code and prompt to reboot if required.

There are various [related articles](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=runtime&ns0=1&fulltext=Search) on the ISXKB wiki.